# Merge [alertmanager] into [prometheus-alertmanager]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Tags [prometheus-alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus-alertmanager) and [alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertmanager) refer to the same application: Prometheus' [Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/).

Former has 747 questions and tag information.

Latter - 82 question, no tag information, and all questions are also tagged with [prometheus-alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus-alertmanager). (There was 17 tagged with only [alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertmanager), but I retagged them earlier)

Please merge tag [alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertmanager) into [prometheus-alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus-alertmanager), and add tag synonym, to prevent creation of this tag again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spot checking several questions with the [alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertmanager), double checking the retags you did earlier, and confirming `[alertmanager] -[prometheus-alertmanager]` returned 0 questions. I've completed the merge into [prometheus-alertmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus-alertmanager) and added the synonym.

```
updating post history, 95 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 82 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 0 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'alertmanager': [alertmanager] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 748
tag remapping of [prometheus-alertmanager] and [alertmanager] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
17 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
8 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym alertmanager -> prometheus-alertmanager was approved!
```

Please note: it will take a little time for search and tags to settle.